# different orientation of list-labels in HTML and XSL-FO

Tags: list, xsl-fo, text-alignment

I am having problems to create a exact similar list via HTML and XSL-Fo. The list labels have different orientations. A HTML ordered list has the labels right-aligned, XSL-FO left-aligned. This is only a minor problem but still annoying.

Example:
http://img69.imageshack.us/i/htmlxslfo.jpg/

Is there any way to change the orientation ind XSL-FO?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `text-align="right"` to your `fo:list-item-label`:

```
<fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()" text-align="right">
  <fo:block>1.</fo:block>
</fo:list-item-label>
```